# Windows XP installation disk for XP Mode under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am running XP mode under Windows 7, for testing / troubleshooting software.

I am trying to install a third party driver(unidrv printer), and I get stuck at

```
Setup failed to locate required files. 
It is required to provide the path of "I386" in Windows installation disc.
Click Browse to provide the appropriate path.
```

I have tried every location containing unidrv or other dlls on the VM (XP running "inside" virtual PC), as well as any `I386` folders, but the installer was not happy.

My guess, it actually wants the installation disk... except, I don't have one !

How can I get an XP `I386` folder from the installation disk, while running XP mode on Windows 7 ?

Comment: There is a c:/I386 folder, I pointed the installer to it but must not have the required info...

Comment: You can still download an XP SP3 ISO from Microsoft's Web Site.  [Link Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25129)

Comment: @N.Greene I guess your comment should be the answer

Comment: Unless you are actually using XPMode for an incompatible printer, why not install printer on Windows 7 and share to the XPMode virtual?

Comment: @ShaunVermaak - apart from the obvious rights issue, i would still need the driver installed in the proper location.

Comment: @N.Greene - how would I be able to use the iso ? would it work to extract it elsewhere and just copy a folder ? (I can't really try... it has been almost 2 years and I am not working in the same environment to be able to test it anymore).

Comment: Use a program to mount the iso. Then when your printer installer asks for the i386 location just point to that mounted .iso file.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with XP Mode a lot at my last job.

The only way to legitimately get the folder you need without buying another copy of Windows XP SP3 is to find another computer with a working Windows XP SP3 installation and copy the folder from there. This is if the printer is incompatible with Windows 7.

If your printer is compatible with Windows 7, then you can install it under Windows 7 and share it to the virtual machine under Windows XP Mode; this is much easier if you have the printer attached locally via USB or parallel port. Usually every resource on your Windows 7 computer is shared to XP Mode unless you elect not to in the Windows XP Mode configuration options.

More details here: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2346469,00.asp

Comment: Yes, yes yes.  This is the correct approach if at all possible.
May I ask what printer?